# Troubles with Php/mysqli - no longer working

Tags: php, mysqli

desperately need some help here. I've recently gone back to a game I had developed a few years ago now that I've got some free time. When I left it all the Php/mysqli code was working perfectly fine. No issues at all.

However, now it is not. For example, when I try to login to the game it I'm getting username and/or password is invalid. Now, obviously I'm using a known username/password.

I've found that it works fine on php5.1 but not on any higher version. I figured I'd have to rewrite the code to suit php7 but I'm having problems with that.

I've tested my code on various online checkers with various php7 versions and I get this error every time...
Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'mysqli' not found in ...
but no syntax errors, no deprecated code.

I have confirmed with my host that mysqli is installed (cpanel) so clearly that's not the issue.

I've also checked using this code snippet ...

```
if (!function_exists('mysqli_init') && !extension_loaded('mysqli')) {
 echo 'you dont have';
 } else {
 echo 'you have!';
 }
```

I have!

I've also run checks that there is a database connection. And when I check the php error log in cpanel I'm not getting any errors at all.

So what's going on? It's as if the data isn't being retrieved from the database. I used to be able to test by changing all the POST syntax to GET so I could manually login via the url but that doesn't work either now.

Any help is much appreciated and thanks in advance.

My login script:

```
<?php 

$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'me';
$dbpass = 'xxxx';
$dbname = 'me_again';

$nameTable = 'table';
$string = '';


$conn = new mysqli($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);

if($conn->connect_error) {
    $string = 'valid=8';

} else {

$username = '';
$userpass = '';
$loginRequest = '';


  if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
  }
   if (isset($_POST['userpass'])) {
    $userpass = $_POST['userpass'];
  }
   if (isset($_POST['loginRequest'])) {
    $loginRequest = $_POST['loginRequest'];
  } 


 if($loginRequest == "login") {

      if ($s = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT `usersalt` FROM `{$nameTable}` WHERE `username`=? LIMIT 1")) {
         mysqli_stmt_bind_param($s, "s", $username);
         mysqli_stmt_execute($s);
         mysqli_stmt_store_result($s);
         if (1 == mysqli_stmt_num_rows($s)) {
            mysqli_stmt_bind_result($s, $usersalt);
            // fetch only 1 result
            mysqli_stmt_fetch($s);

       if ($s2 = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT `username`,`cat1`,`cat2`,`cat3`,`cat4`,`cat5`,`cat6`,`userscore`,`userplayed`,`correct` FROM `{$nameTable}` WHERE `username`=? AND `userpass`=? ")) {
               $hashedpass = sha1($usersalt . $userpass);
               mysqli_stmt_bind_param($s2, "ss", $username, $hashedpass);
               mysqli_stmt_execute($s2);
               mysqli_stmt_store_result($s2);
               if (1 == mysqli_stmt_num_rows($s2)) {
                  mysqli_stmt_bind_result($s2, $res_name, $res_cat1, $res_cat2, $res_cat3, $res_cat4, $res_cat5, $res_cat6, $res_score, $res_played, $res_correct );
                  // fetch only 1 result
                  mysqli_stmt_fetch($s2);
                  header('Content-Type: text/xml');
                  echo "<?xml version='1.0'?>";
                  echo "<".$nameTable.">";
                  echo "<player>";
                  echo "<username>".$res_name."</username>";
                  echo "<cat1>".(int)$res_cat1."</cat1>"; 
                  echo "<cat2>".(int)$res_cat2."</cat2>"; 
                  echo "<cat3>".(int)$res_cat3."</cat3>";
                  echo "<cat4>".(int)$res_cat4."</cat4>"; 
                  echo "<cat5>".(int)$res_cat5."</cat5>"; 
                  echo "<cat6>".(int)$res_cat6."</cat6>";                   
                  echo "<userscore>".(int)$res_score."</userscore>";
                  echo "<userplayed>".(int)$res_played."</userplayed>"; 
                  echo "<correct>".(int)$res_correct."</correct>";                           
               }
               mysqli_stmt_close($s2);

} else {
               $msg = ((is_object($conn)) ? mysqli_error($conn) : (($___mysqli_res = mysqli_connect_error()) ? $___mysqli_res : false));
               $string = 'valid=0';
            }
         } else {
            $msg = ((is_object($conn)) ? mysqli_error($conn) : (($___mysqli_res = mysqli_connect_error()) ? $___mysqli_res : false));
            $string = 'valid=1';

         }
         mysqli_stmt_close($s);
      } else {
         $msg = ((is_object($conn)) ? mysqli_error($conn) : (($___mysqli_res = mysqli_connect_error()) ? $___mysqli_res : false));
         $string = 'valid=2';
      }

}
}

$conn->close();

echo $string;

?>
```

Comment: didn't understand what you want ?

Comment: This url proposes a simple way to test your code: https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/error_reporting

Comment: Do you get _"Class 'mysqli' not found"_ when running your code or is it only when you test it using online checkers? There's a bit too much irrelevant info in your question.

Comment: What do you mean irrelevant info? My code clearly isn't working ie a user can't log in and I've outlined the steps that I have taken thus far to determine why. The class not found error was showing in the cpanel error log but not now. Only in online checkers. I'm asking if this has anything to do with the issue.

Comment: Thank you @Kiko Software

Comment: You say: "It's as if the data isn't being retrieved from the database.", but you seem unable to check this? Why is that? You can, for testing purposes only, put some echo's in your code to tell yourself what it is doing. For instance: `if (1 == mysqli_stmt_num_rows($s2)) { ........ } else echo 'No, or more than one, rows were returned.';`.

Comment: I'm new to this. I'm self-taught. I don't know how to check it properly. I'm asking for advice, if anything appears wrong with my code and all I get is negative responses and lectures. Gees!

Comment: We're not "lecturing" you. We're trying to get to what the actual issue is as your question is a bit confusing. What I mean by irrelevant info is anything that isn't related to the actual issue you're _currently_ having. If you use to have _"Class not found"_ but you don't any more, we don't need to know about it since it's already solved. It only makes the question more unclear and confusing.